# Changing the contents of a jar from a Java program

Tags: java, jar

I would like to be able to create a program that receives a .jar file (another app I've created), and modify it's contents (only add or remove files (not class files or anything), not small modifications).

If it matters, the question in hand is about an app that has a Music library, and supports adding files to it (so that if I open it up with winrar and add music files into the music directory, the app will recognize it on startup), but I would like to save the users some time, and not have them meddle with the jar, so that is why I want to create this program (so that they configure the app music library by themselves and share it with others). There are other features except music that also support this.

Comment: Extract to a temp folder, add, delete files and jar the folder again.

Comment: A jar is actually a "zip" file, just unzip the jar, modify/delete the files as necessary and zip them back

Comment: I know how to do that, but I want to spare my users this process if it's possible..

Comment: *"so that is why I want to create this program"*  So what is your question?

Comment: I asked if it were possible to do so. vanje answered my question. Sorry that there wasn't actually a question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [TrueVFS](http://truevfs.java.net/) (the successor of TrueZIP) to access and modify the content of your JAR file as a virtual file system. With this you can change the JAR file in place without the need to extract and repackage it.

Comment: I want to configure certain actions that can be made (to make abstractions for my users without them needing to know the layout of the jar file)

Comment: As long as _you_ know the layout of the JAR file, I don't see any problems.

Comment: Okay I've read it (at first I thought it was just an outer program). Looks good, I think I'll try it. Thanks!